# Filter all that rows by matching a substring in all the columns in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I expect all the rows that matches a given substring to be written as a list.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["c1", "match", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6","c7","c8","c9"],  
                'col2': [" ","a1","a2","Smatch6","a4"," ","a8"," ","a7"],  
                   'col3': ["Red", "Ted", "Pet", "match1", "Pmatch", "Rmatchd","sample","agadR","Padgadg"]
                    })
```

The output should go as a list into a Dictionary

Data_Dictionary['data'] = o/p of this

tried this code, but it returns nothing

```
resultdf = df1.filter(like='match', axis=0)
```

Expected Result: resultdf

```
    col1     col2     col3
1   match    a1       Ted
3   c4       Smatch6  match1
5   c6                Rmatchd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create boolean mask with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), then check if at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
resultdf = df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('match', na=False)).any(axis=1)]
```

Or use `in` in [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
resultdf = df1[df1.applymap(lambda x: 'match' in str(x)).any(axis=1)]
```

---

```
print (resultdf)
    col1     col2     col3
1  match       a1      Ted
3     c4  Smatch6   match1
4     c5       a4   Pmatch
5     c6           Rmatchd
```

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized approach,

```
>>> df1[df1.sum(axis=1).str.contains('match')]

    col1     col2     col3
1  match       a1      Ted
3     c4  Smatch6   match1
4     c5       a4   Pmatch
5     c6           Rmatchd
```